# Press button and go to random view in Xcode

Tags: iphone, view, xcode

I have three different views in my iPhone app, and when the user presses a button, I need the view to change to either of the three views randomly. How do you do that? I have searched for answer everywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I the only one who thought that he was asking how to switch views randomly in Xcode after reading the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) yourBtnPressed : (id) sender
{
   int i = arc4random() % 3;
   if(i == 1)
   {
           //load first view
   }
   else if(i == 2)
   {
           //load second view
   }
   else
   {
           //load third view
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the arc4random() method to generate the random numbers.If you want to generate numbers upto 100 then use the modular division h 100.like **arc4random() % 100;**.And then you can use your code to switching between the views.

Comment: Uhm Modulo is not the same as dividing!